Total charge on a polarized neutral dielectric
I'm going through Griffith's EM book right now and from problem 4.14 we can see that the total charge on a polarized neutral dielectric is 0 (since it is neutral) the polarization may move around some charge (bound charges) but the total is 0. This makes sense and you can prove it by simply applying the divergence theorem.
However, when introducing the auxiliary field $\vec{D}$ (in subsection 4.3.1 of Griffiths) we write the total charge density in a dielectric material as $$\rho = {\rho}_b + {\rho}_f$$ Where ${\rho}_b$ and ${\rho}_f$ are the volume bound charge density and free charge density respectively
This seems to imply that the total charge on a polarized neutral dielectric is non-zero i.e. $\rho = {\rho}_b$ (as ${\rho}_f = 0$ since it is neutral). That presents a problem when applying the regular Gauss's law for $\vec{E}$. You would get the incorrect result because the total charge in the Gaussian surface (say enclosing the entire object) is in fact 0 and not $\int {\rho}_b d \tau$
My Question: is there a more rigorous derivation of the $\vec{D}$ field that does not run into the problem I have mentioned above? Of course, this would not actually be a problem if you kept the fact that polarized neutral dielectrics have a total charge of 0 in mind.
Griffiths does mention why he left the surface bound charge density out of the derivation for Gauss's law for the $\vec{D}$ field at the end of subsection 4.3.1 I'm not sure I quite understood it but I interpreted it as "The volume bound charge blows up at the surface so we cannot apply the Gauss's law at the surface but everywhere else it works!"

TLDR: I'm mad that I've spent 2 days trying to solve a problem with the wrong assumption (only to find out that the solution was incorrect, because of the wrong assumption) BUT no this is not a shitpost, I do have a genuine question. i.e the mismatch between the total charge on a polarized neutral dielectric in two different parts of electrodynamics

Can you make the question clearer? You say
$$\rho = {\rho}_b + {\rho}_f$$
but you don't show why that would not be zero when integrated (so we do not see the problem!) (Also: do you think the same problem occurs in Jackson? https://archive.org/details/ClassicalElectrodynamics2nd/page/n171/mode/2up?view=theater )

@JosBergervoet When ${\rho}_f = 0$ and when you find the total charge on a polarized object by integrating over it, you will find that it will not be zero. Consider a neutral dielectric with the polarization $P = \frac{k}{r} \hat{r}$.
the free charge will be zero but the total charge density will be equal to the bound charge density so integrating that over the entire volume of the object (a thick spherical shell say for example) you won't get zero

Why?! You get surface charges and volume charges (since the divergence of your P seems to be nonzero), but why do you think they won't add up to zero?

@JosBergervoet yes, so total charge on an object is simply $\int {\sigma}_b d \tau + \int {\rho}_b d \tau$ is it not? and when you apply the divergence theorem you will see that this expression is zero. But what I have a problem with is in the expression $\rho = {\rho}_b + {\rho}_f$ there is no mention of surface charge density and how will it become zero when you integrate it? divergence of P is non-zero, and free charge density is zero therefore when you integrate the total charge density you get a non-zero result

No you do not because "total" includes the surface charge. Whether there is "mention of it" in some book should not bother us, we have to include it in the integral. Further, the integral doesn't actually "become" zero, if your object is isolated it is zero from the start. (And if it isn't isolated, charge can flow to and from it so then there is no mystery left about nonzero total charge. So it remains unclear what you are trying to ask here!)

The total flux is only associated with free charges. It’s the flux density that increases inside the dielectric because dielectric medium offers less resistance to lines of electric field and these can easily pass through dielectric medium than vacuum. This is because of the polarisation of the material. The bound volume charge density is always equal to the bound surface charge density and therefore whenever we integrate the sun becomes zero. Physically the electric flux emanating from any volume terminates on the surface because surface charge density is negative of volume charge density. These volume and surface charge densities show polarisation phenomenon and less resistance to flow of lines of electric field, therefore more lines pass through dielectric which increases D. Consider D = eps*E same as I = GV. As greater conductance increases I with same V so greater eps increases D with same E.
The volume bound charge density would always be accompanied by an equal amount of surface charge density of opposite charge, hence the flux from volume charge density would terminate at the surface charge density. I think you cannot use the bound volume charge density in isolation.

In your question you mention that $\rho_\text{b}=0$ doesn't make sense. It is indeed not true that $\rho_\text{b} = 0$, but the integral of it over the volume of the dielectric is:
$$ \int_V\mathrm{d}V\,\rho_\text{b} = 0. $$
Sometimes this integral includes surface bound charges $\sigma_\text{b}$, which accounts for the fact that some of the bound charges actually accumulate on the boundaries of the dielectric, and it is by including these that the integral evaluates to zero as exoected. This can be taken into consideration mathematically by letting the volume and surface bound charge be given respectively by
$$\rho_1=\rho'_\text{b}, \quad \rho_2=\delta(\partial V)\sigma'_\text{b},$$
where $\partial V$ is the boundary of the volume $V$, and then defining
$$\rho_\text{b}\equiv\rho_1+\rho_2. $$
Then
$$ \int_V\mathrm{d}V\,\rho_\text{b} = \int_V\mathrm{d}V\,\rho'_\text{b} + \oint_{\partial V}\mathrm{d}A\,\sigma'_\text{b} = 0. $$
Note that the Dirac delta function here is exactly why Griffiths says "The volume bound charge blows up at the surface so we cannot apply the Gauss's law at the surface but everywhere else it works!"
Also, your question on "deriving" the $\mathbf{D}$ field isn't clear enough, you should mention the assumptions you are starting from, since usually $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}$ is taken as a definition. This definition helps some calculations, but really has not much physical meaning $^\dagger$, hence the name "auxiliary field".

$^\dagger$ There's some discussion on whether auxiliary fields such as $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ have a consistent physical interpretation (i.e. this PSE post).
